# Active Directory Display all properties in a table

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying to achieve an LDAP query to gather all properties we have about our users without specifying the properties before hand, I would like to display this in a table so used the below code. This works if I uncomment the search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn"); line and will display any other properties I add in the same way but not when I do a full search for all properties.

```
DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = createDirectoryEntry();
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection);

search.CacheResults = true;
//search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");

SearchResultCollection allResults = search.FindAll();
DataTable resultsTable = new DataTable("Results");

//add columns for each property in results
foreach (string colName in allResults.PropertiesLoaded)
    resultsTable.Columns.Add(colName, colName.GetType());

//loop to add records to DataTable
foreach (SearchResult result in allResults)
{
    int tmp = result.Properties.Count;
    DataRow row = resultsTable.NewRow();
    foreach (string columnName in search.PropertiesToLoad)
    {
        if (columnName.Equals("lastlogon"))
        {
            if (result.Properties.Contains(columnName))
                row[columnName] = ConvertDate(result.Properties[columnName].ToString());
            else
                row[columnName] = "";
        }
        else
        {
            if (result.Properties.Contains(columnName))
                row[columnName] = result.Properties[columnName][0].ToString();
            else
                row[columnName] = "";
        }
    }
    resultsTable.Rows.Add(row);
}

gridResults.DataSource = resultsTable;
```

The problem seems to be with

```
foreach (string colName in allResults.PropertiesLoaded)
    resultsTable.Columns.Add(colName, colName.GetType());
```

I expected this to loop all properties when no PropertiesToLoad had been specified but it doesn't is their a way to achieve what I want to.

I know I need a few try catches and other bits in the code as of yet, it's a rough draft.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be done using `DirectoryEntry`, but I don't think the `SearchResultCollection` has all fields.
Try to create a `DirectoryEntry` for every search result, it should have all active directory properties:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
```

Also, note that in the active directory every property can have multiple values (like the MemberOf field), so you'll have to iterate them as well.
I've wrote a similar method, but I chose a `List` with keys/values (it seemed more manageable over WCF. `ILookup` would be optimal, but I couldn't get it to work here). Here it is, stripped from try/catch/using

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
foreach (PropertyValueCollection property in entry.Properties)
   foreach (object o in property)
   {
       string value = o.ToString();
       list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(property.PropertyName, value));
   }
```

Answer (score 12):

You can iterate through all properties this way:

```
foreach (SearchResult searchResult in allResults)
{
  foreach (string propName in searchResult.Properties.PropertyNames)
  {
    ResultPropertyValueCollection valueCollection =
    searchResult.Properties[propName];
    foreach (Object propertyValue in valueCollection)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Property: " + propName + ": " + propertyValue.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

Is that what you need?

Answer (score 2):

Came across this thread while looking on how to do this myself.
Instead i found a different way of doing it, and seems to be working fine.

```
return ((DirectoryEntry)UserPrincipal.Current.GetUnderlyingObject()).Properties.PropertyNames;
```

Its loading perfectly find in a Combobox anyhow.
Just incase anyone else comes across this thread.

Comment: This might be more helpful to me if your comment related a UserPrincipal to a DirectorySearcher, or something relevant. I may just not know enough about this object, but I see no valid object type, and I cannot resolve this.

Comment: This is using the newer System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.  So you would need to add a reference and using statement.