# Partial Search on SearchResult collection - Active Directory, all Groups

Tags: c#, linq, collections, active-directory

I have a list of group names for the active directory stored in a :-

```
SearchResultCollection AllGroupsResults;

 DirectorySearcher ds = null;
 DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(domainPath); <--- passed ina
 ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
 // Sort by name
 ds.Sort = new SortOption("name", SortDirection.Ascending);
 ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
 ds.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Group))";
 AllGroupsResults = ds.FindAll();
```

The user enters a string in a textbox and I want to perform a partial match for groupnames in the collection, something like this :-

```
var partialGroupNameMatches = 
          AllGroupsResults.FindAll(er => er.GroupName.Contains(searchString));
```

But my syntax doesn't work, as the collection doesn't have a definition for "FindAll"... Does that mean I need to convert my collection to a custom defined list, or is there another way that I am unaware of?

** Edit **

```
var partialGroupNameMatch = AllGroupsResults.Cast<SearchResult>().ToList()
                           .FindAll(o => o.Properties["name"].Contains(searchString));
```

Thanks to the suggestions I have my syntax right... but results returned either with the Where or FindAll clause is - 0....even for a generic string like "a" or "A"....

I can put a break point on my AllGroupsResults collection and see that it has 2 properties 'adspath' and 'name'....both of which have over 5000 values in them..

What is really baffling to me is:-

```
 var q2 = AllGroupsResults.Cast<SearchResult>().Select(o => o.Properties["name"]).ToList();
 var partialMatch = q2.Where(o => o.Contains(searchString));
```

While q2... has all the results for GroupNames in it... when I do the partialMatch query on it, I have 0 results...no matter how generic my query string is.

Comment: [I would look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091115/active-directory-display-all-properties-in-a-table. You should make the search results populate a DirectoryEntry. You can then search the directory Entries based on their properties.

Comment: Server side sorts are very expensive in AD. They also have the potential to fail if you have a really big result set. If you can, you should do the sort client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SearchResultCollection` implements non-generic `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, so you can `Cast<>()` and use regular LINQ from there on in:

```
var partialGroupNameMatches = 
      AllGroupsResults
          .Cast<SearchResult>()
          .Where(er => er.GroupName.Contains(searchString));
```

When I try this, it's telling me `SearchResult` doesn't have a `GroupName` property, so I'm guessing `SearchResult` is not the correct type here. Ryan Carlisle has suggested [an answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091115/active-directory-display-all-properties-in-a-table).

But now we're talking about the `name` property. Also, remember that this is AD, so everything is horrible. `sr.Properties["name"]` is a collection of values, not a string. Both it and String have a `Contains` method, but they're different `Contains` methods that do different things. So when you call `sr.Properties["name"].Contains("a")`, you're actually asking a collection of names if one of the names is the string `"a"`. None is, so it never returns true.

Instead, let's call `Contains` on each name in that collection:

```
var partialGroupNameMatches = 
      AllGroupsResults
          .Cast<SearchResult>()
          .Where(sr => 
              //  Return true if *any* name contains searchString
              sr.Properties["name"].Cast<String>()
                .Any(s => s.Contains(searchString))
          );
```

Note that the `sr.Properties["name"]` collection contains objects, and it's not very LINQ friendly, but as long as it implements `System.Collections.IEnumerable` -- and just about everything under the sun does, if it's even remotely a collection -- we can `Cast` and we're in business.

And now I'm getting the expected results in `partialGroupNameMatches`.

I'm leaving the rest of it to you!

Comment: I tried :-  var partialGroupNameMatch = AllGroupsResults.Cast<SearchResult>().ToList().FindAll(o => o.Properties["name"].Contains(searchString));

However even with the most generic string 'a', I get no results

Comment: @Philo What don't you like about Where? Anyway, see what you get here: `var q1 = AllGroupsResults.Cast<SearchResult>().ToList(); var q2 = AllGroupsResults.Cast<SearchResult>().Select(o => o.Properties["name"]).ToList();` -- set a breakpoint, and look in the debugger watch window to see what you get in q2 and q2.

Comment: Also `var n = AllGroupsResults.Count;`. How many results are in `AllGroupsResults` before the query?

Comment: I checked all of that Ed, AllGroupResults have a count of 5943... and has two properties, adspath and name... all of the properties have appropriate values, as my gridView are being populated by them

Comment: I have nothing against the Where clause, I have tried both Where and FindAll and they both seem to return 0 results... which is why I am a bit perplexed.

Comment: @Philo What did you see in `q2` results as in my comment above, the query for all the names?

Comment: q2...shows me the list of all values for the property 'name'

Comment: var q2 = AllGroupsResults.Cast<SearchResult>().Select(o => o.Properties["name"]).ToList();

 var partialMatch = q2.FindAll(o=>o.Contains('a'));

returns 0 results

Comment: @Philo What about `q2 = q2.Where(s => s.Contains("a"))`? That's a string `"a"`, not the character `'a'`.

Comment: sorry Ed. Thats what I meant.

Comment: somehow the Select statement works great on the SearchResult collection, but not the Findall or where clause....

Comment: @Philo Can you add a complete example to your question, with the search that produces AllGroupsResults, and all succeeding steps down to where you call `q2.Where(s => s.Contains("a");` and get zero results. Oh, wait -- are these strings all-caps by any chance? How does `q2.Where(s => s.Contains("A");` work for you?

Comment: @Philo What does a domainPath look like? It throws an exception on the name of our local domain, so it can't be that.

Comment: domainPath is a global variable that I have defined... "LDAP://xxxxyy".. If that didn't work, I wouldn't be getting any group Results

Comment: @Philo Yeah, I found something valid for me locally. Here's the problem: sr.Properties["name"] is not a string, it's `System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection`. Now I remember why I hate working with AD with such a passion.

Comment: lol. So am I correct to think, that I have to manually convert the whole collection into a custom defined list and then search on that list?

Comment: @Philo Answer updated again, now correctly searching all the name property values of each SearchResult.

Comment: great explanation. Thanks Ed!

Comment: @Philo My pleasure. I can't believe it took me so long to remember that SearchResults.Properties values are collections of garbage instead of single values; I've been through this horror before.

Answer (score 1):

The method `FindAll` is a method of `List<T>` and not of `ICollection<T>`. So even if your `SearchResultCollection` implements `ICollection` there isn't any method called `FindAll`. There are two options, as I can think for your problem

1. Create a `List<T>` and call there the `FindAll` method.
2. Call the `Where` extension method, since `SearchResultCollection` implements `IEnumerable`.

Comment: It looks like I have to manually convert my collection to a list... the where clause on my searchResult doesn't find any results, even with the most generic search critieria such as 'a'